# Is there a robust way of checking whether a prospective Git alias name is available?

Tags: git, git-alias

Git allows you to create your own custom Git verbs, or aliases, using

```
git config [--global] alias.<alias-name> "<replacement-text>"
```

If you're not very familiar with Git commands, though, you may choose an alias name that corresponds to an existing Git verb; as an extremely dumb example, consider

```
git config --global alias.log show
```

No panic; according to `git config --help`:

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored.

Fine, but, in that case, **Git won't tell you that your new alias will be ignored**.

Therefore, I'm wondering whether there is a robust (and future-proof) way of checking whether my prospective alias name correspond to an existing Git verb, before actually defining the alias.

I was thinking of searching for `<alias-name>` in the output of `git help --all`, but the latter contains more than just a list of all Git verbs, so I'm not sure how robust such an approach would be...

Any idea?

Comment: What's the exit code of the command when your alias was not created? Whether you check beforehand or check the exit code afterwards should not matter

Comment: @knittl Whether the name already corresponds to a Git verb or not, `git config --global alias.<alias-name> <replacement-text>` outputs nothing; therefore, there is no immediate way to tell whether the newly defined alias is "valid" or not. That's my problem.

Comment: yeah, just verified: the exit code is 0, and the alias is added to your `.gitconfig` (or `.git/config`), but only ignored when actually calling the alias. Maybe one should write a patch for Git to warn users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just run `git help <command name>`.

- If the command exists, that will bring up the man page for the command in question
- If the command is an existing alias, you'll get something along the lines of `'git l' is aliased to 'log'`
- If the command does not exist, you'll get an error message

Comment: Thanks. That's a remarkably simple idea that I hadn't thought about `:)`